# How to check if no records were created among all models in RSpec/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know how to check if no records were created in one model.

```
expect{Counter.increment}.to_not change{Counter.count}.by(1)
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/expect-change#expecting-no-change

Now, is there a way to check if no records were created among all models in RSpec/Rails?

Comment: Why do you think that you need such a broad test? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I need to check if no side-effect occurs when a method called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can check the number of records in all app's tables:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).inject(0){ |result, a| result += a.all.size }
```

Regarding using it in test case - hmm.. I don't see any reason to do so - consider refactoring the test rather then resorting to such hackery stuff.

If you still want to use it it test.. well, go with what was in my original answer:

```
expect(your_something).to_not change{ ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).inject(0){ |result, a| result += a.all.size } }
```

Comment: I think you are right. Test cases should not be so hackery.. Anyway this is good answer, thanks!